# How to create dropdown option in html using javascript

Tags: javascript

how to use javascript in HTML
given an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for

```
var i;
    var html = '<div class="add_more_ticket_div">\
                    <div class="form-group">\
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ticket name *</label>\
                        <div class="col-sm-6">\
                        <input type="text" name="ticket_name[]" value="" class="form-control allowOnlyLetter">\
                        <p>Early bird, Standard, V.I.P</p>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="form-group">\
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>\
                        <div class="col-sm-6">\
                        <input type="text" name="ticket_desc[]" value="" class="form-control allowOnlyLetter">\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="form-group">\
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ticket price *</label>\
                        <div class="col-sm-3">\
                        <input type="text" name="ticket_price[]" value="0.00" class="form-control allowNumDot">\
                        <p>Set zero if ticket is free</p>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="form-group">\
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ticket quantity *</label>\
                        <div class="col-sm-3">\
                        <input type="text" name="ticket_quantity[]" value="" class="form-control allowOnlyNumber">\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="form-group">\
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Max no. of ticket that each user can buy</label>\
                        <div class="col-sm-3">\
                        <select name="ticket_can_buy[]" class="form-control">\
                            '+for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {+'<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>'+}+'</select>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="col-sm-3">\
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn bg-orange btn-flat remove-ticket-section">- Remove</a>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                </div>';
    $('.add_more_ticket_div:last').after(html);
```

how to use javascript in HTML
given an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for

Comment: Mixing JS with HTML is a bad practice

Comment: The _Unexpected token_ error tells you what to look for. Look for the character that's output in the error, usually a `;` and see what is immediately before that. Other than that, work through some javascript tutorials to gain a firmer foundation and knowledge before trying something like above. I don't say this to be rude, I say this because there are far easier ways of doing what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Have a look at that part where you try to run a `for` loop within the string concatenation - that does not look good

Answer (score 1):

You should not mix your JavaScript and your HTML. Instead, you can populate your select from your JavaScript using `querySelector` to get a reference to your select to then set its `innerHTML` property.

You can generate your list of options my first generating a range from 0 to 30:

```
Array.from({ length: 30 }, (_,i) => i) // gives [0, 1, 2, 3... 29]
```

Then you can map over it to generate an array of options:

```
arr.map(i => `<option value="${i}">${i}</option>`)
```

And then you create a string by joining the array elements with `join('')`.

```js
const selectHTML = Array.from({ length: 30 }, (_,i) => i)
    .map(i => `<option value="${i}">${i}</option>`).join('');

document.querySelector('#mySelect').innerHTML = selectHTML;
```

```html
<div class="add_more_ticket_div">
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ticket name *</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" name="ticket_name[]" value="" class="form-control allowOnlyLetter">
      <p>Early bird, Standard, V.I.P</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" name="ticket_desc[]" value="" class="form-control allowOnlyLetter">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ticket price *</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="ticket_price[]" value="0.00" class="form-control allowNumDot">
      <p>Set zero if ticket is free</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ticket quantity *</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">\
        <input type="text" name="ticket_quantity[]" value="" class="form-control allowOnlyNumber">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Max no. of ticket that each user can buy</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <select id="mySelect" name="ticket_can_buy[]" class="form-control"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn bg-orange btn-flat remove-ticket-section">- Remove</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```